# Interface inheritance - Issue with double inheritance

Tags: design-patterns

I need to define 4 interfaces with names and methods as given in the first picture.
[image: Pic 1]

But, I need to maintain the following relationship:

- LivingBeingMutable "is a" LivingBeingConst
- AnimalConst "is a" LivingBeingConst
- AnimalMutable "is a" LivingBeingConst
- AnimalMutable "is a" LivingBeingMutable
- AnimalMutable "is a" AnimalConst

So, I modified the interfaces with inheritance as shown below:
[image: Pic2]

But the problem is, AnimalMutable is getting two instances of "GetLifeSpan()" methods (one from AnimalConst and another from LivingBeingMutable). Could anyone let me know what is the correct way to design it?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a famous multiple inheritance problem called "The Diamond Problem".

You need concepts such as virtual base classes - "Virtual Inheritance" (C++).

For more information, look here:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/117-multiple-inheritance/

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/118-virtual-base-classes/

You could either try to use single inheritance, as almost concepts done with multiple inheritance can be also done with single inheritance, and there are many widely used OOP Languages that support only single inheritance.

Other languages do not support pure multiple inheritance but provide alternative mechanisms to get some of the benefits of the multiple inheritance and avoid such problems instead. Interfaces in Java is one such mechanism, as you just define the signature methods and the implementation is always responsibility of the class that implements them, although a class could implement many interfaces.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple inheritance is safe in interfaces

This would have been a diamond problem in c++.

If you are using Java / C# (guessing from your mention of interface) you should not have any problem.

**Interfaces were invented to solve the diamond problem.**

In stead of method prototype, if you had a member variable being inherited, the question of "*where did it come from*" would have been meaningful.

Since it's just prototype of a method (it's same anyways), **it does not matter if the same method is being inherited from multiple interfaces.** So you can safely create those interfaces without any problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Interfaces were invented to solve the diamond problem" - what? Diamond problem doesn't exist if working exclusively with interfaces, but interfaces surely weren't invented for this.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you can specify some more reasons behind interfaces which were impossible to solve using classes. I wrote to best of my knowledge, and would like to know more. Thanks.

Comment: Interface represents a *design concept* - a contract, which is being complied by each realizing class. That is the main purpose of interfaces. Technically speaking, interface is a private case of class, therefore everything that is solvable by using interface, can be solved by using class (unless the language poses limits on purpose, e.g. C#/Java)

Comment: That's correct. But contracts can also be imposed using classes. The main reason that they are imposed using interfaces is that safe multiple inheritance can be achieved. Right? My question was : Was there any OTHER reason behind interfaces which could not be solved using classes? Thanks again.

Comment: No. Assuming you're talking about C++, nothing forces you to use interface (i.e. class with only pure virtual members) over class with non-pure virtual members. The choice of one over the other should be made by design considerations (in most cases interface would be a better design choice but it's not a must), technical issues such as diamond problem are secondary.

Comment: Well I agree about it being better design choice but it is better ONLY because it does not let diamond problem arise. So I still stand by it. That's my opinion though. But thanks anyways for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: In this entire conversation you did not answer my question first question at all (my second comment). You just kept telling me that it's wrong. I'll be grateful if you can tell me at least ONE problem that interfaces solve which can not be solved using classes. I know only one and that makes it reason behind interfaces for me. If you know more, please share it.

Comment: In software engineering, interface is a concept. Class is entirely different concept, therefore comparing their usages doesn't make much sense. Interface can be represented by a class with pure virtual members only in C++ or it can be an Interface construct
of C#/Java and it can even be simply a set of function declarations in C (which naturally has nothing to do with diamond problem).